# Check duplicate content with Selenium Builder

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-builder

Im using Selenium Builder to make a Selenium Test. I want to check if there's some duplicated content on the site. It can be text "This is an example" or div ids "#id_to_catch". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

By using the **findElements** function:

```
Boolean dups = (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'This is an example')]")).size()>1);
```

Comment: And how this is applied to SeleniumBuilder?

Comment: It most likely isn't.  My bad, sorry.

Comment: Selenium Builder exports on a JSON format. Can I add that to that format? If yes, I saved the value from and xpath to a variable EXAMPLE1. Can I replace 'This is an Example' to EXAMPLE1 and that's it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium Builder at all, and I also assumed you were using Java with just Selenium.  I don't know how your SB works at all.  If you can make/pass xpaths then the xpath I provided will return the element or elements that match.  It would be up to your SB, I suppose, to determine if the returned value is zero, one, or more elements.  My example is how I would accomplish what you are attempting to do just using Java and Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I can export it to PHP - WebDriver